# CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION property is not supported by compiler version error in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

CUDA Kernel function present in `a_kernel.cu` file. I need to generate fatbin from the kernel so that fatbin will be loaded in `a_test.cpp` for testing the kernel function via the CUDA driver API. I am able to run this process via the NVCC command in the command prompt. But when trying to use CMake, it throws an error. Does anyone  have a clue about the following error?

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (set_property):
  CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION property is not supported by compiler version .


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

`cmakefile.txt`:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(CUDA_CPP_TEST) # LANGUAGES CUDA CXX

# Find CUDA
#find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

# Add CUDA include directories
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(./include)

add_library(a_kernel OBJECT ./src/a_kernel.cu)
set_property(TARGET a_kernel PROPERTY CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION ON)

# Executable and Link CUDA libraries
cuda_add_executable(test ./test/a_test.cpp ./src/a_src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? cuda_fatbin_compilation is a pretty new addition. Your version might be too old

Comment: I am using cmake version 3.28.0-rc5 @talonmies

Comment: Why do you use old `find_package(CUDAToolkit)`, `cuda_add_executable`, etc. instead of CUDA language supported by modern CMake?

Comment: @Tsyvarev [`find_package(CUDAToolkit)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) is not old, it arrived in 3.17. The legacy one is [`find_package(CUDA)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html) which is deprecated since 3.10. But I agree that it doesn't look like OP needs the Toolkit instead of just the `CUDA` language. The Toolkit is only needed for linking libraries from the CUDA Toolkit.

Comment: Without a language given, CMake assumes C or C++. So it only looks for a C or C++ compiler and tells you that that host compiler doesn't support `CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION`, which is to be expected. Just put the commented out languages into the `project` command. You might not  need any `find_package(...)`. Get rid of `CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY` and `CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY`. Replace `cuda_add_executable()` with `add_executable()`. In case you have calls to the CUDA Runtime API in one of the `.cpp` files, take a look at the `findCUDAToolkit` documentation to see the available targets.

Comment: And given that [`CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION.html#cuda-fatbin-compilation) came with 3.27, you should have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)`.

Comment: Rereading the question, it seems like you use the CUDA Driver API in `a_test.cpp`. In that case `find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)` is correct and you want to link the `CUDA::cuda_driver` target.